# Tzolk'in wealth card meaning

Tags: tzolkin

What does this wealth card mean? My guess is: I get 10 corn, one less worker and... Maybe get 1 less corn per turn... The rules book doesn't say anything about it.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1mkG201ZcEndGdKQy1hQTZZNFk/view?usp=docslist_api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Tile comes from [Tzolk'in - the mini-expansion 1](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgameexpansion/134380/tzolk-mayan-calendar-mini-expansion-1) a goodie from Spielbox magazine.

Here is how to use it:

> **Bonus Starting Wealth - Cistern**
>
> Your tribe has figured out how to draw water out of the surrounding
>   soil and and store it in an underground cistern. The ecological impact
>   of this feat of engineering harms the other tribes
>
> If you choose this Starting Wealth Tile, you get 10 corn. Each of your
>   opponents starts with 1 less corn. (An opponent whose Starting Wealth
>   Tiles provide no corn is not affected.)
>
> If you draw this tile when placing dummy workers, it indicates that
>   you will play this game with one less dummy worker than usual (11
>   instead of 12 in a two-player game or 5 instead of 6 in a three-player
>   game).
>
> *Help your culture grow and flourish, and the gods will smile upon you.*

Note that this mini-expansion is also supposed to come with a monument tile: the Granary.